# Advice on Implementing a simple Delete button in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dynamic

So my issue that I have is implementing a functioning delete button for my GUI.
While I have just about everything working, I have been stumped with trying to implement this function. What it does is as i click the 'Add' button, it creates a row with text fields  and a check box. The 'Delete' works in the sense that it only deletes the most recent field create once I click on the checkbox to delete it. My intention is that the GUI works in a dynamic way to where I can click whatever check boxes and delete only those specific rows with the boxes checked.
I've researched methods of using an ItemListener but I'm still wrestling with that as I figure its the most proficient way to go. I've also done the storing the components in an array to iterate over. I feel I'm close with what I have now, any advice appreciated.

Below is the 'Add' button code to create new rows in my GUI. Then there is the 'Delete' button code which places the components in an array, but only deletes the most recent row created that has been checked.

```
add = new JButton("Add");
 add.addActionListener(e ->{
      rowPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4,5,5));
     for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){

         rowPanel.add(new JTextField(8));
     }
     for(int l=0; l < 1; l++){
         rowPanel.add(new JCheckBox(), BorderLayout.EAST);

     }

     infoPanel.add(rowPanel);
     infoPanel.revalidate();
     infoPanel.repaint();

 });


 delete = new JButton("Delete");
 delete.addActionListener(e -> {
     Component[] components = rowPanel.getComponents();
     for(Component c : components){
         if(c instanceof JCheckBox){
             if(((JCheckBox)c).isSelected()){
             infoPanel.remove(rowPanel);
            }
         }
     }


     infoPanel.revalidate();
     infoPanel.repaint();


 });
```

Comment: Your rowPanel variable holds only the last row. You need to iterate through your rows.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Stefan Reich, so my for each loop I assume I need to be revised? And I thought I was using the rowPanel variable to generate more rows which it currently does.

Comment: You need to keep a list of the rows you made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JTable as a container and add a custom row that is a checkbox and a textfield. This way you just have to get the checkbox's event and see what index in the JTable it is located and delete it.

This might be useful:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender